# Error in in sysft_Name while restoring database

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a .bak file which gives the following error while restoring:

> System.data.sqlclient.sqlerror:The path 'E:' has invalid attributes. It needs to be a directory. It must not be hidden, read-only, or on a removable drive.

[image: Image of error message]

But I verified that the directory is not read only. Anyone know how to restore the three files being restored ( .mdf,.ldf, and sysft)?

The script i had used for restoring database has been given below.

RESTORE DATABASE [new] FROM  DISK = N'E:\a\L11.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'itest' TO N'E:\a\3.mdf',  MOVE N'itest_log' TO N'E:\a\4.ldf',  MOVE N'sysft_test' TO N'E:\a',  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10
GO

Comment: Script your restore command out to a new window using the script button on the restore dialog box and paste that into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a "\" at the end of the path.

```
RESTORE DATABASE [new] FROM DISK = N'E:\a\L11.bak' WITH FILE = 1, MOVE N'itest' TO N'E:\a\3.mdf', MOVE N'itest_log' TO N'E:\a\4.ldf', MOVE N'sysft_test' TO N'E:\a\', NORECOVERY, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10 
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the section:

**MOVE N'sysft_test' TO N'E:\a'** to **MOVE N'sysft_test' TO N'E:\a\sysft_test.ndf'**

Then rerun as see if the backup works.

Comment: SQL 2005 puts the full text index into a folder not a file.  SQL 2008 and newer puts it into a normal data file.

Comment: @mrdenny tough crowd.... :). I thought it to be a secondary data file.